# Meaning of amicus omnium amicus nullorum

Tags: sentence-translation, translation-check

What is the meaning of *amicus omnium amicus nullorum*?

Everybody's friend is nobody's friend?

Answer (score 5):

That is correct!

There is an implicit *est* ("is") between *amicus omnium* and *amicus nullorum*.
It is quite typical to leave this word out; otherwise the translation is very straightforward.
*Amicus* is a friend, and then we have the plural genitives *omnium* and *nullorum*, "of everybody" and "of nobody".